# How to show pictureBox by hovering over comboBox items?

Tags: c#, windows

I want to show the picture for each item of combobox by hovering over it. I am having difficulty doing it. I wrote the following so far. Please tell me what i doing wrong. Thank you.

```
private void mouseHoverIndex(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 1)
        {
            Coke.Visible = true;
        }
        if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 2)
        {
            Coke.Visible = false;
            Sprite.Visible = true;
        }
    }
```

The drink names are picture boxes.

Comment: Your code is checking the `SelectedIndex` property of your combobox. It will not be selected if it is only hovered. What client side technology are you using?

Comment: Try HitTest to determine where your mouse is

Comment: What do you mean what client side technolgy? i am using visual studio tahts all, i don't know what you mean

Comment: how can i try HitTest?

Comment: Can you show the code of your combobox?

Comment: He means: What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
__Always__ tag your question correctly! Most likely it is Wnforms..? I was wrong about Hittest, sorry. In fact things are not so easy. Are you sure you need to use a ComboBox? Also: MouseHover is a bad choice as it will (at best) fire once until you leave the control. You could start a Timer in the MouseMove, but using a ListView and do a listview1.HitTest in the MouseMove is simpler and much more versatile.

Comment: I'm using Windows application. sorry about the confusion. i'm new to the site. I decided to use MouseEnter instead.

Comment: the visibility of pictures is set to false by default